# Average of of 2 coordinates

Tags: c#

So I am making a graph of the average between to lists of coordinates.

So I have been looking all over and can't seem to find any information on how I can find the average of the 2 lists of values. When I try I get an error "the index was outside the matrix boundaries" and when I got it to work I just made a graph where the years where extremely high and the graph itself were looking insane. What i do is importing 2 parts of(data/data2) information with Json.

```
        //
        // Data
        //

        int tal = dataSet.dataset.value.Count;
        //Add items in the listview
        int[] yData = new int[tal];
        int[] xData = new int[tal];
        int k = 0;

        foreach (var item in dataSet.dataset.dimension.Tid.category.label)
        {
            xData[k++] = int.Parse(item.Value.ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tal; i++)
        {
            yData[i] = dataSet.dataset.value[i];
        }

        //
        // Data2
        //

        int tal2 = dataSet2.dataset.value.Count;
        int[] y2Data = new int[tal2];
        int[] x2Data = new int[tal2];
        int j = 0;

        foreach (var item in 
        dataSet2.dataset.dimension.Tid.category.label)
        {
            x2Data[j++] = int.Parse(item.Value.ToString());
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < tal2; p++)
        {
            y2Data[p] = dataSet2.dataset.value[p];
        }


         This is the part
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
        int[] ySum = new int[xData.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < xData.Length; i++)
        {
            ySum[i] = (yData[i] + y2Data[i]) / 2;

        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


        List<int> GenUd = new List<int>(yData.ToList());
        textBoxGenUd.Text = GenUd.Average().ToString();
        List<int> GenInd = new List<int>(y2Data.ToList());
        textBoxGenInd.Text = GenInd.Average().ToString();


        chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
        chart2.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        chart2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;



        for (int i = 0; i <xData.Count(); i++)
        {
            series1.Points.AddXY(ySum[i], x2Data[i]);
        }

        MySecChart2 mc3 = new MySecChart2(series1); 
        mc3.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, welcome to SO. Regarding your question, that seems like a lot of code which is not directly related to the issue you are having. It would be helpful if you could just put a specific code snippet and point where exactly the error is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

mine is just an educated guess -  if the exception occurs at the following:

```
     This is the part
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    int[] ySum = new int[xData.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < xData.Length; i++)
    {
        ySum[i] = (yData[i] + y2Data[i]) / 2;

    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

My diagnosis would be that `yData[i]` and `y2Data[i]` they dont have the same length and of `xData.Length` define into the loop definition.

Was perhaps supposed to be yData.Length in the loop definition?

Comment: It didn't work, the error are still there, but thanks.

Comment: Can you post the dataset's you are using?

Comment: Found the problem. I s